# Is there a way to convert column to target fields in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: etl, kettle

As follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Yuz.png)

How to convert value of name field to target fields in Pentaho Kettle?

Json file describing the data structure that means How many headers in table:

```
 [
                    {
                        "description": "employee_number",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "char",
                        "name": "employee_number",
                        "size": -1
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "name",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "char",
                        "name": "name",
                        "size": -1
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "gender",
                        "required": false,
                        "size": -1,
                        "type": "char",
                        "name": "gender"
                    }
      ]
```

Json file describing real data:

```
    [
{
    employee_number:123,
    name:"jack",
    gender:"female"
},
{
    employee_number:123,
    name:"jack",
    gender:"female"
}]
```

Thank you for your patience ！！

Comment: If the data source is a SQL Table, you have nothing to do. The PDI makes all the work for you. You can check it with a `right-click / show output fields`. If this does not answer, tell us which step you are using.

Comment: The data source is JSON from Rest API . in two step, 1. to fetch only data structure from Rest Client  2. to fetch data

Comment: Please enter a 5 lines example of the 2 json you are trying to read.

Comment: thanks, I 've done it